# Posts sorted by year in accordion

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, accordion, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type for testimonials and it has few posts. I'm trying to create an accordion which shows posts by year. So when you click on the year it displays all the posts for that year (see screenshot below).

[image]

I have got it somewhat working, problem is when I click on the year, it only shows one post for that year. Here's the code -> https://pastebin.com/3F98dcEU

```
            <?php get_header();?>
            <style>
            .accordion {
            background-color: #eee;
            color: #444;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 18px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            text-align: left;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 15px;
            transition: 0.4s;
            margin-bottom:20px;
            }

            .active, .accordion:hover {
            background-color: #ccc; 
            }

            .panel {
            padding: 0 18px;
            display: none;
            background-color: white;
            overflow: hidden;
            }
            </style>
            <div class="container-fluid testimonial-header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                        <h1>Testimonials</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container testimonial-content">
                <div class="block-1">
                    <h2 class="heading">Delivering Exceptional Customer Service</h2>
                    <p class="sub-heading">Being locally owned and operated, our objective is to provide exceptional client service delivered by our professional team. We take great pride in building homes that are beyond expectation, on time and on budget.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid py-5 archive-testimonial">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <?php 
            global $wpdb;

            $posts = $wpdb->posts;

            //Get all unique years as "years" from posts where post type is equal to testimonials

            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(YEAR(`post_date`)) as years FROM $posts WHERE post_type = 'testimonials' ORDER BY years DESC"; //Get all post year list by DESC


            //Loop through all results and use date_query param https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters


            $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

            foreach($result as $rs) { ?>
                <button class="accordion"><?php echo $rs->years ;?></button>
                <?php $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'testimonials',
                    'post_per_page'=> -1,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'orderby'   => 'date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'date_query' => array(array(
                        'year'=> $rs->years,
                    ),),

                );

                $loop = new WP_Query($args);

                if($loop->have_posts()) {

                    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="panel testimonial-grid-archive testimonial-loop-ah">
                            <div>
                                <?php 
                                    if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                                        <div style="text-center">
                                                    <div class="testimonial-image-aden" style="background-image:url('<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>');"> </div>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php } else { ?>
                                                <div class="testimonial-image-aden placeholder-testimonial-image"> </div>
                                            <?php } 
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                            <div class="testimonial-content">
                                <p class="testimonial-highlight"><?php echo the_field('testimonial_highlight') ;?></p>
                                <p><img class="star-ratings-ah" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/stars.png" alt=""></p>
                                <div class="testimonial-text-ah">" <?php the_field('testimonial_text'); ?> "</div>           
                                <p class="person-title-archive">- <?php the_title() ;?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    <?php endwhile;

                }
            }
                        ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
            var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
            var i;

            for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                panel.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                panel.style.display = "block";
                }
            });
            }
            </script>
            <?php get_footer();?>
```

You could try the code with built-in post type and you'd see what I'm talking about.

My approach to this might be completely wrong.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your JavaScript code only makes the first panel that follows a button visible, but you have multiple of those (one for each post.) You need to either loop through all panels coming after such a button and make them visible, or group them into one container element to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your panel div is inside your while loop, and so it is repeated for each post. You should have it outside of your loop, so it is only generated once for every year.

Change this:

```
while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="panel testimonial-grid-archive testimonial-loop-ah">
        <div>
            <?php 
                if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                    <div style="text-center">
                                <div class="testimonial-image-aden" style="background-image:url('<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>');"> </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <div class="testimonial-image-aden placeholder-testimonial-image"> </div>
                        <?php } 
                        ?>
                    </div>
        <div class="testimonial-content">
            <p class="testimonial-highlight"><?php echo the_field('testimonial_highlight') ;?></p>
            <p><img class="star-ratings-ah" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/stars.png" alt=""></p>
            <div class="testimonial-text-ah">" <?php the_field('testimonial_text'); ?> "</div>           
            <p class="person-title-archive">- <?php the_title() ;?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;
```

to this:

```
<div class="panel testimonial-grid-archive testimonial-loop-ah">
    <?php while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <div>
        <?php 
        if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
            <div style="text-center">
                <div class="testimonial-image-aden" style="background-image:url('<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>');"> </div>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="testimonial-image-aden placeholder-testimonial-image"> </div>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial-content">
            <p class="testimonial-highlight"><?php echo the_field('testimonial_highlight') ;?></p>
            <p><img class="star-ratings-ah" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/stars.png" alt=""></p>
            <div class="testimonial-text-ah">" <?php the_field('testimonial_text'); ?> "</div>           
            <p class="person-title-archive">- <?php the_title() ;?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @markmoxx, it worked.  I did try this with only 'panel' class before the while loop and it didn't work. Thanks much :)

Comment: Glad to hear :) Any chance you can mark as correct?

Comment: Accepted. Thanks.